# Django database query spanning across multiple relationships

Tags: django, python-3.x, django-models, django-views

Given the models below:

```
class Assets(models.Model):
    assettag = models.CharField()
    ...
    pass

class Employees(models.Model):
    loginname = models.CharField()
    pass

class Item(models.Model):
    descr = models.CharField()
    asset = models.OneToOneField('Assets')
    ...

class Assignments(models.Model):
    employeeid = models.ForeignKey('Employees')
    assetid = models.ForeignKey('Assets')
    ...
```

I can make a query that returns all `Item` models which contain a certain `descr` or a certain `assettag`, using Q objects.

```
Item.objects.filter(Q(asset__assettag__icontains = query) |
                    Q(descr__icontains = query) #|
                    ).order_by('asset__assettag')
```

Would it be possible to also include `employeeid__loginname` somehow? I couldn't figure out a way to do so.

I want to retrieve the `Assets` that are refereneced in the `Item` table and which belong to a certain `Employee`.

Comment: Unrelated, but the value of a model's ForeignKey field is the related model instance, not the related record id, so in `Assignment` your ForeignKey fields should be named `employee` and `asset` (the orm will add the underlying `employee_id` and `asset_id` attributes and DB fields).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First add a "related_name" in Assignments model.

```
assetid = models.ForeignKey(Assets, related_name='asset_related_name')
```

then you can use this `asset__asset_related_name__employeeid__loginname`

Comment: Thanks, it kinda works, but for some reason I get multiple hits on the same item. Some items are returned 2 times, other 4 times, other just 1 time. Have any ideea why that could be?

Comment: You don't need to add a related name - Django provides a default one if you don't.

Comment: @BogdanPrădatu, because one "loginname" will be common to many instance of Assignments model. it's one to many relation (ForeignKey). one item instance for more than one assignments instances.

Comment: @sandeep Of course, you're right. Any way of retrieving just the last entry? Q objects don't seem to have a "last" method. I've managed to get the desired output by filtering another field which is 0 for the last entries in the Assignment table. If I didn't had this possibility, would there be a way to add a "last" clause to a Q object?